# How to use another variable name or How to flatten entity in JPA Projection for nested object

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I'm making an api for querying nested entity with Spring Data JPA Projection.

## My Code

The Entity:

```
@Entity
class User {
    @Id
    var userId: String
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    var address: Address
}

@Entity
class Address {
    var userId: String
    var street: String
    var city: String
    var country: String
}
```

The Repository:

```
interface UserView {
    val name: String
    val address: AddressView

    interface AddressView {
        val city: String
        val country: String
    }
}

@Repository
interface UserRepository : JPARepository<User, String> {
    fun findAll(): List<UserView>
}
```

## Expected Response

```
{
    "name": "example",
    "city": "example-city",
    "country": "example-country"
}
```

## My code produces

```
{
    "name": "example",
    "address": {
        "city": "example-city",
        "country": "example-country"
    }
}
```

## I Tried

I tried another view to flatten object:

```
interface UserView {
    val name: String

    val addressCity: String
    val addressCountry: String
}
```

But this case, the variable naming is too complicate.

I want to solve this problem with projection. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: i don't have experience in kotlin, but to do it in JPA: (i) you can try `join` also like `from User  u join u.address` which result in one table.

Comment: I don't wanna use native query for solving this.. Is there another way using JPA API?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this in JPA other than @NamedNativeQuery

Comment: *I want to solve this problem with projection*. You can solve this was a projection. What is the issue you face with using that approach?

Comment: I want to flatten that response object like above JSON. But projection can't flatten that response object like below JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In JPA, you can do this using `@NamedNativeQuery` only:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
name = "getUser",
query = "SELECT u.name, a.city, a.country FROM User u and Address a where a.userId = u.id ", resultClass=UserView .class)
@Entity
class User {
...
}
```

For Reference [hibernate-named-query](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-named-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data class UserView(name: String, city: String, country: String)

@Repository
interface UserRepository : JPARepository<User, String> {
    @Query(value = "select new your.pkg.UserView(u.name, u.address.city, u.address.country) from User u")
    fun findAllFlat(): List<UserView>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Value` and combine more fields or even access the fields of objects.

From the [spring-data-rest documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts):

```
You can create a projection that combines the two data fields in the preceding example together, as follows:

@Projection(name = "virtual", types = { Person.class })
public interface VirtualProjection {

  @Value("#{target.firstName} #{target.lastName}") 
  String getFullName();

}
Spring’s @Value annotation lets you plug in a SpEL expression that takes the target object and splices together its firstName and lastName attributes to render a read-only fullName.
```

Flattening also works for me:

```
@Value("#{target.document.title}")
String getDocumentTitle();
```